# How to get the nth percentile of a distribution in R?

Tags: r, distribution

"We considered the significance if the observed overlap between occurrences of x and y was outside the 84th percentile of the expected overlap distribution (corresponding to one standard deviation in a normal distribution)."

I'm confused of the sentence from a literature.

Here is the sample data.

```
data <- seq(0,100,0.1)
```

I wonder how I can get the 84th percentile of the data distribution using R.

Thanks.

Comment: Use the  `quantile` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`quantile(data, .84)` should do the trick. See `?quantile` or this [tutorial](http://www.r-tutor.com/elementary-statistics/numerical-measures/percentile).

Comment: Thank you. Does 84th percentile of a data mean the 84th percentile of the expected overlap distribution (corresponding to one standard deviation in a normal distribution)? Sorry for the stupid question.

Comment: That depends on the probability distribution underlying your data. If that is the normal distribution, then yes. Then the 84th percentile is +1 standard deviations from the mean. The vector you provided above does not indicate a normal distributed, though.

Answer (score 2):

For a list of percentiles, just use:

```
quantile(data, c(0.1,0.5,0.9))
```